# VueJS: How to Access the Previous Item in v-repeat

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a table that fetches some JSON from a Laravel API to populate the rows. I am using VueJS and the **v-repeat**:

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-repeat="entry: entries">
    <td>@{{ entry.id }} </td>
    <td>@{{ entry.distance }} km</td>
    <td>@{{ entry.consumption }} l</td>
    <td>@{{ getPrice(entry) + ' €'}}</td>
    <td>@{{ getCost(entry) + ' €'}}</td>
    <td>@{{ getAverageConsumption(entry) + ' l' }}</td>
    <td>@{{ getAverageCost(entry) + ' €' }}</td>
    <td>@{{ getCostPerDay(entry) + ' €' }}</td>
    <td>@{{ this.getDate(entry) }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now I want to calculate the AverageCostPerDay(). Problem is, that I need to access the previous item in the iteration to make a comparison on how many days passed.

How do I access previous items with v-repeat in VueJS? And how could my **getCostPerDay()** method look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `$index` variable along with `entries` like this

```
        <td>@{{ getCostPerDay(entries[$index-1]) + ' €' }}</td>
```

For more reading about `$index` have a look at [Displaying Lists](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html)

Comment: This only works in v1, as $index was removed in v2. Please see my v2 answer.

Answer (score 17):

In v2 of vue.js, you need to this form of `v-for` to get the index:

```
v-for="(item, index) in items"
```

You can then use `items[index - 1]` to get the previous value (making sure your function checks it isn't `undefined`).

Answer (score 2):

```
<div v-for="grade, i in grades">
    <input v-model="grade.name">
    <input v-model.number="grade.percent">
    <div v-if="i > 0 && grade.percent > grades[i - 1].percent">
        Invalid: percent must be lower than previous grade
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a method that adds a point to the current index, like this:

```
getNextItemIndex: function(entry) {
    var currentIndex = this.entries.indexOf(entry);
    return (currentIndex + 1);
},

getNextItemDate: function(entry) {
    var nextDate = moment(this.entries[this.getNextItemIndex(entry)].date);
    return nextDate;
},

getTimeDifferenceToNextEntry: function(entry) {
    var entryDate = moment(entry.date);

    var timeDifference = entryDate.diff(this.getNextItemDate(entry), 'hours') / 24;

    return timeDifference.toFixed(3);
},

getCostPerDay: function(entry) {
    var costPerDay = this.getCost(entry) / this.getTimeDifferenceToNextEntry(entry);


    return costPerDay.toFixed(2);

    // console.log(dateDifference);

    var priceRatio = entry.price / nextPrice / 1000;

    return priceRatio.toFixed(3);
    // return previousEntry.price;
}
```